# php how to wrap html tags for each search words,

Tags: php

How to wrap html tags for each search words, such as highlight words. I tried my code here, but nothing changed. Where is the problem, or is there have any other good way? thanks.

```
<?php
$sentence = "for loops are the most complex loops in PHP. They behave like their C counterparts";//original
$search = 'php counterparts';//search words
$str = explode(' ',$search);//explode every search word
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    if($str[$i]!=''){ //make sure if $str[$i] is not empty, do $newstr.
        $newstr .= '\'<b>'.$str[$i].'</b>\','; //wrap <b> tag for search words
    }
}
$newstr = substr($newstr, 0, strlen($newstr)-1);//remove last common, combine a array

$new = str_ireplace(array($str),array($newstr),$sentence);
echo $new;
?>
```

Comment: Can you better explain what it is you are trying to do? Your code while very commented doesn't quite explain things either. What output are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is the array bounded at 10 iterations? Why do you use a string to hold the modified words? Why the regex demarcations when your not using a regex function for the substitution?

Don't even try to fix this code - start again from scratch:

```
$sentence = "for loops are the most complex loops in PHP. They behave like their C counterparts";//original
$search = 'php counterparts';//search words
$srch_words = explode(' ',$search);//explode every search word
$replace_words=array();
foreach ($srch_words as $key=>$val) {
     $replace_words[$key]='<b>' . $val . '</b>';
}
$sentence=str_ireplace($srch_words, $replace_words, $sentence);
```

Answer (score 3):

This would be one way:

```
<?php

$words = array('blue', 'red');
foreach ($words as $word) {
   $matchWords[] = "/$word/i";
}
$string = 'Red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet. More red, bluebell';

$string = preg_replace($matchWords, '<span class="keyword">$0</span>', $string);

echo $string;
```

Would output:

```
<span class="keyword">Red</span>, orange, yellow, green, <span class="keyword">blue</span>, indigo, violet. More <span class="keyword">red</span>, <span class="keyword">blue</span>bell
```

You can then use CSS to apply the highlight. You might want to modify the regex to just match whole words

Comment: I used this code, and for the most part it works great. But for the same of this example. If matchWords have 'span' in them, it will wrap existing span words in span tag, and the result will be very messed up. Any suggestions how I could solve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "for loops are the most complex loops in PHP. They behave like their C counterparts";//original
$search = 'PHP counterparts';
$explode = explode(" ", $search);

foreach($explode as $word){
  $str = preg_replace("/$word/i", '<strong>$0</strong>', $str);
}

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try it this way. It's more failesafe and less index-hassle. Might be a little slower, but that should hardly be an issue.

```
<?php
function highlightWords(array $words, $text) {
    $pattern = '#(';
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($words); ++$i) {
        $pattern .= ($i > 0) ? '|' : '';
        $pattern .= preg_quote($words[$i]);
    }
    $pattern .= ')#i';
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'highlightMatch', $text);
}
function highlightMatch ($matches) {
    return sprintf('<b>%s</b>', $matches[0]);
}
```

Less pretty but maybe faster would be:

```
<?php
function highlightWords (array $words, $text) {
    $find = array();
    $replace = array();
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $find[] = $word;
        $replace[] = sprintf('<b>%s</b>', $word);
    }
    return str_replace($find, $replace, $text);
}
```